# Evaluate: $ \sum _ {k=1}^{n}{\frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}t^k(1-t)^{n-k}}$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Evaluate:
$$ \sum _ {k=1}^{n}{\frac{k}{n}\dbinom{n}{k}t^k(1-t)^{n-k}} $$

$\dbinom{n}{k}$stands for the usual binomial coefficient giving the number of
ways of choosing $k$ objects from n objects.

---

Totally stuck.How can I able to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using
$$
    \binom{n}{k} \frac{k}{n} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}
$$
Then
$$
   \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} \binom{n}{k} t^k (1-t)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} t^{k} (1-t)^{n-k} = t \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} t^{k} (1-t)^{n-1-k} = (t+1-t)^{n-1} t = t
$$

Answer (score 6):

Consider $f(x,y)=(x+y)^n$. Expand, differentitate w.r.t to $x$, multiply by $x$ and plug $x=t$, $y=1-t$. If you know about Berstein Polynomials, you shouldn't be surprised the result is just $t$.

**Spoiler** Differentiate $$n(x+y)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom nkx^{k-1}y^{n-k}$$ Multiply by $x$, divide by $n$ $$x(x+y)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac kn \binom nk x^{k}y^{n-k}$$

Set $x=t,y=1-t$ $$t=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac kn \binom nk t^{k}(1-t)^{n-k}$$

Comment: how should I able to tackle the term (k/n)

Comment: It will appear if you follow what I wrote above.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Since $y=1-t$ (or rather $1-x$ ), when you differentiate with respect to $x$, how can you consider $y$ a constant? Isn't $y$ a function of $x$? In other words,
$$x(x+y)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac kn \binom nk x^{k}y^{n-k}$$
should be applicable only when $y$ is a constant, right?

Comment: No, the substitution is made after the differentiation, @mathguy

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  Exactly. But isn't the substitution valid only if $y$ is not a function of $x$? Because, in the previous steps, you have assumed that $y$ is not a function of $x$, right?

Comment: @Mathguy The previous steps are irrelevant. The manipulation is entirely abstract and valid, even if $x,y$ carrie no meaning whatsoever and we define $D(x^k):=kx^{k-1}$.